# Looking for LGBT book about French mages and vampires

Tags: story-identification, magic, vampire

Replying to [Book about a girl with magic, who can teleport and is mated to a powerful vampire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/260361/149815), I remembered another urban fantasy book series I read a while ago. I would like to revisit it, but I cannot remember its name and I seem to have deleted the ebook version I had of them (and I do not remember where I bought them either).

I read it about 8 years ago in English. There were at least four books, but it could be more.

What I remember:

- The story plays in Paris in France.
- The book was about a war between mages similar to Harry Potter in so far, that a powerful, charismatic evil mage started a rebellion in the mage community leading to a kind of civil war.
- In the first book, a mage tries to get the vampires to help them in the war. As a token of good will, he let the vampire drink of his blood. This starts some kind of bond, in which both the vampire and the mage get more powerful. They experiment and it turns out that this bond occurs randomly between one mage and one vampire, so they have a large meeting where each vampire sips from each mage. Some are matched up, while others are not.
- There are the following (not necessarily romantic) couples explored in the books:

  - The mage and vampire first shown in the first book. They are kind of naive and all lovey-dovey.
  - The mage's best friend and a vampire outsider. Their names are Thierry and Sebastian, but I do not remember who is who. The vampire outsider was once friend with the head vampire, but was shunned due to some past conflict.
  - The mage's 'black sheep' and the head vampire. The 'black sheep' is named Raymond. He once followed the charismatic bad guy, but became disillusioned and tries to redeem his past errors.
  - A fierce warrior-women and a chauvinistic vampire. They seem to work well together in the beginning, but he cannot accept that she is her own women, so she says rejects him. He starts to stalk her. I do not remember how their relationship ended, but in later books the women mourns of what could have been seeing some of the other couples, so they never got together.
  - An old-fashioned mage and a female vampire. The female vampire runs some kind of restaurant for vampires, which the mage sees as a kind of brothel. I remember an argument, but I do not remember whether they reconciled. The female vampire decorates herself with Henna.
  - A very old mage and a very old vampire - kind of. The do not bond, but the others think that they could.
- Each mage is specialized at one element. (Raymond: earth, the warrior-women: fire)
- At one point in the books, the mages had to perform some kind of powerful magic, where a mage with each element had to be there. They were helped by the vampires during this scene.
- In another book they helped in the clean-up of a environmental catastrophe on a french colonial island (Réunion I think).

I searched on goodreads and with google / duckduckgo mostly using the names, but there are too many authors / other books with Raymond or Thierry. Furthermore, I do not remember whether the mages were mages, wizards or sorcerers and nowadays there are simply too many vampire to easily google them. I also do not know anymore whether magic was kept secret or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is *[Alliance in Blood](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3194217-alliance-in-blood)*, (or one of the other [*Partnership in Blood* series of books](https://www.goodreads.com/series/45736-partnership-in-blood)) by Ariel Tachna.

> Can a desperate wizard and a bitter, disillusioned vampire find a way
> to build the partnership that could save their world?
>
> In a world rocked by magical war, vampires are seen by many as less
> than human, as the stereotypical creatures of the night who prey on
> others. But as the war intensifies, the wizards know they need an
> advantage to turn the tide in their favor: the strength and edge the
> vampires can give them in the battle against the dark wizards who seek
> to destroy life as they know it.
>
> In a dangerous move and show of good will, the wizards ask the leader
> of the vampires to meet with them, so that they might plead their
> cause. One desperate man, Alain Magnier, and one bitter, disillusioned
> vampire, Orlando St. Clair, meet in Paris, and the fate of the world
> hangs in the balance of their decision: Will the vampires join the
> cause and form a partnership with the wizards to win the war?

Comment: The review for book 5 [here](https://joyfullyjay.com/2014/05/throwback-thursdayseries-spotlight-partnership-in-blood-series-by-ariel-tachna/) mentions all three of the names from your question; "***Thierry** and **Sebastian** finally start a physical relationship, though before Sebastian, Thierry was straight and had only been with woman. And Jean and **Raymond** take their partnership to the next level.*"